# Comparing percentage values in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell in Excel that has data stored in it in percentage format, for example -8.40% . I want to compare if the value in the cell is less than(in magnitude) -8.5% or not, if yes then some actions will follow.

So how do i write a VBA macro code to compare the value?

I tried

```
`If ActiveSheet.Range(range_name).Value > "-8.50%" Then 
Perform some action`
```

But this doesn't seem to work.. so how should i do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-8.5%` is nothing but `-8.5/100` which ultimately is `-0.085`

So change your code to

```
If ActiveSheet.Range(range_name).Value > -0.085 Then
```

Comment: Exactly. Even though excel will automatically change the cell formatting to percentage on entering a "%", the values will be handled as floating point internally. So just because it looks different, doesn't mean the values are different.